# User with Contribute and modify cannot add Items to a list

Tags: active-directory, authorization

I am currently using SharePoint 2013.
I have just added a user to an Active Directory Group with contribute permissions to a Calendar. Unfortunately, the AD group can contribute  but the user can't. 
If I check the permissions, everything seems fine with the user having the right permissions. Still it can't add items to the list.

If I grant the permissions directly, instead of through the Active Directory Group ,
the user can operate correctly.

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of Domain Access Tokens and Security Token Caching.

An access token is not updated until the next logon, which means that if you add a user to a group, the user must log off and log on before the access token is updated.

http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2014/05/active-directory-groups-and-sharepoint-security/

This is due to the fact that Sharepoint imports the group membership information from Active Directory on a regular basis. the Frequency depends on configuration of your User Profile Synchronization service in central Admin. Profile synchronization is described nicely here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg188041.aspx#groups

[Why are user permissions set in AD not updated immediately to SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14649/why-are-user-permissions-set-in-ad-not-updated-immediately-to-sharepoint)